# Disable Return after i in vim

Tags: neovim

I have a bad habit of pressing the <kbd>Return</kbd> immediately after pressing the <kbd>i</kbd> key, when the <kbd>o</kbd> key would save keystrokes. I would like to disable the <kbd>i</kbd>-<kbd>Return</kbd> combination to help me break this habit.

I tried to add

```
imap <Return> <NOP>
```

to my `~/.config/nvim/init.vim`, but this disables pressing it in insert mode entirely. Is there a way to disable it only upon immediately entering insert mode?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this combo:

```
nnoremap <silent> i<CR> :echoerr "Use o instead"<CR>
```

This will issue the error only if you press both `i` and `<Enter>` within `'timeoutline'` (default one second).